# PNP Powershell Script Document Library Inventory

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, pnp-powershell

Hi I am using this script to return all documents in a site collection.  I have some custom columns in the library but I am unsure how to add them to the script, specifically the internal name.  Is there a way to get all column names so that I can put them in the csv ?

```
#Connect to SPO
Connect-PnPOnline -Url "https://site.sharepoint.com/sites/07/li" 
#Store in variable all the document libraries in the site
$DocLibrary = Get-PnPList | Where-Object { $_.BaseTemplate -eq 101 } 
$LogFile = "C:\users\$env:USERNAME\Desktop\SPOFolders.csv"
$results = @()
foreach ($DocLib in $DocLibrary) {
    #Get list of all folders in the document library
    $AllItems = Get-PnPListItem -PageSize 1000 -List $DocLib -Fields "SMTotalFileStreamSize", "Author"
    
    #Loop through each files/folders in the document library for folder size = 0
    foreach ($Item in $AllItems) {
       # if ((([uint64]$Item["SMTotalFileStreamSize"]) -eq 0)) {
            Write-Host "Empty folder:" $Item["FileLeafRef"] -ForegroundColor Yellow
    
            #Creating object to export in .csv file
            $results += [pscustomobject][ordered] @{
                CreatedDate      = [DateTime]$Item["Created_x0020_Date"]
                FileName         = $Item["FileLeafRef"] 
                CreatedBy        = $Item.FieldValues.Author.LookupValue
                ContentType      = $Item["ows_ContentType"]
                FilePath         = $Item["FileRef"]
                SizeInMB         = ($Item["SMTotalFileStreamSize"] / 1KB).ToString("N")
                LastModifiedBy   = $Item.FieldValues.Editor.LookupValue
                EditorEmail      = $Item.FieldValues.Editor.Email
                LastModifiedDate = [DateTime]$Item["Modified"]
                CaseManager      = $Item["Case_x0020_Manager"].Email)
            }
        }#end of IF statement
    }
#}
$results | Export-Csv -Path $LogFile -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the below command to get all columns in the library:

```
Get-PnPField -List "<Library Name>"
```

[image]

Reference: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/get-pnpfield?view=sharepoint-ps